# Present Perfect with a phrase "in the past"

Tags: present-perfect

> His car is very reliable, and he rarely has any trouble with it. But he *has had* a couple of difficulties *in the past*.

Can you justify using Present Perfect in this sentence? Since "*in the past*" was used, the time frame must have been established, and, as I know, Present Perfect does not go with an exact time frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An established time frame can be "last night" or "when I was little". "In the past" or "before" are too general to be considered an exact time frame. The *present perfect* (in its used from your example) talks about an unspecified moment *in the past / before now* anyway, so you can use these two safely with it.

When the present perfect is used as in your example, "in the past" is implied. For example:

*I've had some difficulties with the car.*

It is obvious I have had them *before now, in the past*. It is not necessary to mention that. In your example it is mentioned for contrast because the first sentence refers to *now*.

Answer (score 1):

The point about the present perfect is that it always implies (or specifies) an event or series of events occurring in a range of time, the end point of which is now.  (The event or events occur before now, however.)  The simple past always implies a point of time or a range of time the end point of which is before now.

> Between January 2010 and now I have bought three new cars.
>
> Between January 2010 and January 2013 I bought three new cars.

Comment: Do you agree with another  answer?

Comment: If you are asking if I agree with the other answer, then yes.  Otherwise, my question is "which other answer?"  :)

Comment: OK, thanks. This thing is very confusing, that you can write "another" (= _an_ other), but cannot write "theother".

Comment: True.  English spelling is very inconsistent.  Consider was, fuzz, does, and because.  Then rough, dough, through, trough, bough.  There is a reason that they have national spelling championships in English!